# How can I use another jQuery version for one specific plugin only?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-scrollify

[Scrollify](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify) does not work with jQuery 1.12.4, which I need to run. So I need to add another jQuery version, okay so far. But how can I make sure that Scrollify uses that other jQuery version while the rest of my page does not?

Comment: Short answer, don't. There are lots of plugins which do what you require, and are up to date. Using multiple versions of jQuery in a project is just asking to give yourself a headache in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Scrollify works with jQuery versions 1.6 and up. Including jQuery 1.12.4.